# SDK fuctions not getting called in shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

One of my clients are calling SKD's function in shouldStartLoadWithRequest, sometimes that method not getting called and also not printing any logs which i added in that method. SDK variable declared and initialised globally, also i tried to initialize the sdk before calling the method but its not working. From my side its working fine, my client is in mexico.

```
Framework * abc = [Framework sharedInstance];
[abc someMethod];
```

Comment: why don't you use `[[Framework sharedInstance] someMethod]` ?

Comment: Yeah, i tried but no use.

Comment: `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is deprecated starting from iOS 12. Also its only called when the request has a response, e.g., the requested URL sent some response. Check if your client has access to the URL in question.

Comment: Actually that method is getting called but nothing happend.

Comment: Please edit your question with a more complete vision of your code... It's hard to help only seeing two lines of code.

Comment: Actually we are calling that method only, in that method we are making api call. I have added some nslogs in that method even that logs also not getting printed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206335/discussion-between-naveen-reddy-and-carla-camargo).